# Absolute Positioning Causing Flickering

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have two pages that are making use of absolute and relative positioned elements at the top of the page. The issue is that the lower content is coming in sooner than the header content which is causing a flickering effect on these pages:

http://test.icpm.biz/blog/index.html

http://test.icpm.biz/blog/article.html

It is most noticeable in Chrome.

CSS:

```
.single-article figure {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    background: @black;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.single-article figure img {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    min-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.block {
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 1px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 3000;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='no-js' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta content='IE=edge' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'>
    <!-- Website Title -->
    <title>Institute of Certified Professional Managers</title>
    <!-- Metatag Info -->
    <meta content='' name='description'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
    <!-- Favicon and Apple Icons -->
    <link href='img/favicon.png' rel='shortcut icon'>
    <link href='img/apple-touch-icon.png' rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='57x57'>
    <link href='img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png' rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='72x72'>
    <link href='img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png' rel='apple-touch-icon' sizes='114x114'>
    <!-- CSS Stylesheets -->
    <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Include Google Fonts -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neuton:200,300,400,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script charset='ISO-8859-1' src='http://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/popover-v1.js'></script>
    <script src='js/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js'></script>
    <script src='js/respond.js'></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> <script> document.createElement('header'); document.createElement('nav'); document.createElement('section'); document.createElement('article'); document.createElement('aside'); document.createElement('figure'); document.createElement('figcaption'); document.createElement('footer'); </script> <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Featured Article -->
    <div class='single-article'>
      <figure>
        <img alt="Article Bg" data-src="<1043:bullet-proof-mobile.jpg, >1044:bullet-proof.jpg" data-src-base="img/article-bg/"/>
      </figure>
      <div class='block'>
        <div class='container'>
          <div class='row blog-logos'>
            <div class='col-12 show-mobile hide-tablet'>
              <div class='icpm-blog-logo'>
                <p>
                  <a href='index.html' title='Return to Homepage'>
                    <img alt='ICPM Logo' src='img/ICPM-Logo-Home.png'>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6'>
              <div class='mgmt-blog-logo'>
                <p>
                  <a href='index.html' title='Return to Homepage'>
                    <img alt='MGMT Blog Logo' src='img/mgmt-blog-logo.png'>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6 hide-mobile show-tablet'>
              <div class='icpm-blog-logo'>
                <p>
                  <a href='index.html' title='Return to Homepage'>
                    <img alt='ICPM Logo' src='img/ICPM-Logo-Home.png'>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-12 col-desktop-9'>
              <h1><a href="article.html" title="Article Title">Bullet-Proofing your Career and Seeing what a Two Line Title Looks like</a></h1>
              <h4>Susan Mucha, CM</h4>
              <p>September, 24 2015</p>
            </div>
            <div class='col-3 hide-mobile show-desktop'>
              <p>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Blog Articles -->
    <div class='container wrapper'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6 col-desktop-4'>
          <div class='articles'>
            <figure class='effect-overlay'>
              <img alt='Bullet Proof Photo' src='img/article-bg/bullet-proof.jpg'>
              <figcaption>
                <div>
                  <h2>Bullet-Proofing Your Career</h2>
                  <h4>Susan Mucha, CM</h4>
                </div>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6 col-desktop-4'>
          <div class='articles'>
            <figure class='effect-overlay'>
              <img alt='Mid Career Photo' src='img/article-bg/mid-career.jpg'>
              <figcaption>
                <div>
                  <h2>Why &amp; How to Make a Mid-Career Job Change</h2>
                  <h4>Tracey Renzi, CM</h4>
                </div>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6 col-desktop-4'>
          <div class='articles'>
            <figure class='effect-overlay'>
              <img alt='Career Photo' src='img/article-bg/career.jpg'>
              <figcaption>
                <div>
                  <h2>Leaving the Military: Now What?</h2>
                  <h4>Sean Forney, CM</h4>
                </div>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-12 col-tablet-6 col-desktop-12'>
          <div class='articles'>
            <figure class='effect-overlay'>
              <img alt='Military Photo' src='img/article-bg/military.jpg'>
              <figcaption>
                <div>
                  <h2>3 Things They Didn't Tell me in College</h2>
                  <h4>Michael Davis, CM</h4>
                </div>
              </figcaption>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the image you are loading in the  element doesn't have any dimensions. So the solutions would be:

a) Give dimensions to the image loaded inside the figure, eg:

```
width="100%
height="550"
```

b) Even better, don't give the figure a `max-height:550px`, but rather a `height:550px` and use the image as a `background-image` and scale it accordingly using `background-size:cover`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to initially hide the element that take longer to load and then fade them in nicely.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".myElement").delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

And in your css

```
.myElement{
 display:none
}
```

Also many of the relative positioning in there is unnecessary.